# How to convert array of image url into base64 encoded

Tags: reactjs, base64, filereader

```
const [imageSelected,setImageSelected]= useState();
const [imgUrl,setImgUrl]= useState();

useEffect(()=>{
   let reader = new FileReader();
   let newArray=[];
   images.forEach((image)=>{
    let img= image;
    reader.readAsDataURL(img);
    reader.onloadend=()=>{
       newArray.push({image:{ string:reader.result}})
    }
    }
   )
   setImgUrl(newArray);

},[imageSelected])

const ImgPreviewHandler=(event)=>{
   let imageData=[...event.target.files]
   setImageSelected(imageData);
 }

<input type="file" multiple accept="image/*" onChange={ImgPreviewHandler}/>
```

In the code I am taking multiple input, then one state is updated on change, when this sates changes in going in useEffect then here i am converting each value of array in base64, but it is assigning undefined.

Is there any other way to convert ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why setImgUrl is assigning undefined is that reader.onloadend is asynchronous, and setImgUrl is being called before newArray is fully populated with the base64 strings.

Here is how i uploaded a picture to my server you can use if as a reference:

```
  const [image, setImage] = useState();
  const [createObjectURL, setCreateObjectURL] = useState();
  
  const uploadToClient = (event) => {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      const i = event.target.files[0];
      setImage(i);
      setCreateObjectURL(URL.createObjectURL(i));
    }
  };
  
  const date = Date.now()
  const imageUploadToServer = async (event) => {
    const body = new FormData();
    date.toString()
    body.append("file", image);    
    body.append("date", date.toString())
    let userId = session.user._id; 
    console.log(userId)
    const res = await axios.post("/api/accounts/upload",body);
  };
```

To fix your issue you can use Promises to wait for all the images to be loaded before setting the state:

```
const [imageSelected, setImageSelected] = useState();
const [imgUrl, setImgUrl] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  const loadImage = (image) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
        resolve({ image: { string: reader.result } });
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(image);
    });
  };

  if (imageSelected && imageSelected.length > 0) {
    Promise.all(imageSelected.map(loadImage)).then((newArray) =>
      setImgUrl(newArray)
    );
  } else {
    setImgUrl([]);
  }
}, [imageSelected]);

const ImgPreviewHandler = (event) => {
  let imageData = [...event.target.files];
  setImageSelected(imageData);
};

<input type="file" multiple accept="image/*" onChange={ImgPreviewHandler} />;
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but if I want to make my code work, what changes I should make? I have tried by making separate async function and importing and calling it in useEffect for each value of url but still it shows undefined